# Error "curl: (28) Operation timed out after 300714 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received" in docker-compose installation

Tags: docker, docker-compose, ubuntu-20.04

I tried to install docker-compose on my Linux server with ubuntu v20.4 according to the instruction.
Website: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-docker-compose-on-ubuntu-20-04

I typed command below:

```
sudo curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.29.2/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

and unfortunately i just see error below:

```
curl: (28) Operation timed out after 300714 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received
```

would you please let me know how i can resolve error above?

Comment: can you ping the outside world?  `ping google.com` or does this command time out?  did you install docker first?

Comment: Yes, I can. but I think this happened because of some Internet filtering in my country.